# Visualizing the transformation from surface to contour plot in Windows

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, visualization, online-resources, programming

According to my understanding, [this](https://youtu.be/WsZj5Rb6do8?t=120) transformation from a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to contour lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a contour plot in $\mathbb{R}^2$ was made in Grapher, a program exclusive to Apple.  Is there a way to view this type of transformation for a desired multivariable function in MATLAB, Python, or some free tool online or compatible with Windows?  Is there also a way to view the inverse transformation from a contour plot in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to contour lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for such a user supplied function?

Comment: Yes, you can make such a plot in Matlab using [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) and [`contour3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html), and similarly in Python with [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)'s [mplot3d](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-toolkits-mplot3d-py) toolkit. // If you can replicate the original animation, can't you also visualize the inverse transformation just by playing the animation backwards?

Comment: @Rahul:  I think the OP's question assumed you are given *only* the projected contour plot and need to infer the three-dimensional surface.... no "playing a projection backward."

Comment: @David: Well at the end of the sentence they say "for such a user supplied function". So I assumed one has the function itself and not merely a finite number of its contours.

Comment: @Rahul I meant that either the user can supply the algebraic function for the surface and the program transforms the surface ultimately into a contour plot, or the user can supply the algebraic function for the contour plot and the program transforms the contour plot ultimately into a surface.

Comment: What does that mean, "the algebraic function for the contour plot"? Don't both plots visualize the same function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Rahul Err, yeah that sounds correct, so your suggestion of playing an animation backwards would be good.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In *Mathematica* (which certainly has *Windows*-compatible versions):

```
surface = 
 Plot3D[2.5 + Sin[x^2 y], 
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 Mesh -> 10,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.009]],
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]];

slice = 
 SliceContourPlot3D[2.5+Sin[x^2 y], 
 {"ZStackedPlanes", 1},
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.009]]];

Show[surface,slice]
```

I think you may want to get access to more powerful tools than freeware.

The only way you can go from a contour plot up to a three-dimensional plot is to first infer the function.